# How to install docker in Windows VM on a Ubuntu host?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I am trying to install a docker on a Windows VM (windows server 2016).

This VM is on an Ubuntu 16.04 host. This VM is created using VirtualBox (independent from docker or docker-machine).

When I try to install docker on the windows VM, it says "virtualization must be enabled in BIOS". When I check whether virtualization has been enabled in the windows task manager, it says virtualization is not capable. I have already enabled Hyper-V in the VM

The question is: is it possible to install docker inside a Windows VM on an Ubuntu host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not possible to run Docker on Windows VM hosted on Ubuntu. Your Windows VM is already a virtual machine. Installing docker on this Windows requires Hyper-V which is an additiona layer of virtualization. This is not possible.